# How many people could be fed in this world?

Tags: agriculture, technology

I have heard in the radio in one discussion between an  executor and economist that:

> The world of a humans have technology with the ability to feed 200
> billion of its kind but the existence of 2 billion of them like
> children are hungry.

So I have asked here to know is this right and if possible I would like to know some tags for finding some academic papers or media posts about the above context.

Comment: Where did you read or hear that the world can feed 200 billion humans? Can you provide a source or citation?

Comment: The FAO has plenty of reports on how to feed 9$-$10 billion by 2050. It will be challenging but doable. Feeding 200 billion doesn't matter, it is not a realistic number of humans in the foreseeable future.

Comment: @Nic, I have heard it from one online radio and in one discussion with Executor and economist, so I like to know is this technology available to feed around 200 billion humans?

Comment: Welcome. [I posted a semi answer in the meta discussion of this question](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1940/20559)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, 200 billion people is an unrealistic world population. However, according to the FAO and the U.N. (e.g. [1](https://www.fao.org/sustainable-development-goals/goals/goal-2/en/), [2](https://www.unep.org/news-and-stories/story/how-feed-10-billion-people), [3](https://www.fao.org/3/x0262e/x0262e05.htm)), current levels of food production are more than sufficient to feed today's world population (a similar claim is also included in the 2014 IPCC [report](https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/2018/02/WGIIAR5-Chap7_FINAL.pdf)).

Many of the reports of the FAO suggest steps in the direction of not having the present contradictions such as the [huge amounts of food waste while millions of people are hungry](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/environment/article/141013-food-waste-national-security-environment-science-ngfood), of keeping food production sustainable, etc. But it should be emphasized that the present levels of food production are already sufficient to feed the global population and that world hunger / undernourishment / food insecurity are not because of scarcity or inability to produce enough for all.